# Taking a Screen Shot of an Embedded Linux Framebuffer

Tags: imagemagick, embedded-linux, framebuffer

I'm running Embedded Linux on an evaluation kit (Zoom OMAP35x Torpedo Development Kit). The board has an LCD and I would like to be able to take screen shots convert them into a gif or png. I can get the raw data by doing the following: "cp /dev/fb0 screen.raw", but I am stumped on how to convert the image into a gif or png format.

I played around with convert from ImageMagick (example: "convert -depth 8 -size 240x320 rgb:./screen.raw -swap 0,2 -separate -combine screen.png"), but have been unable to get an image that looks right.

Does anyone know of any other tools that I could try out? Or does anyone have tips for using ImageMagick?

Comment: Is "Embedded Linux" a very specific kernel version / configuration, or just a general name for Linux running on Embedded? Related: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/25063/capturing-area-of-the-screen-without-a-desktop-environment

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Take a look at [fbgrab](http://fbgrab.monells.se/), an application that does just that (it saves the framebuffer content as a png).

Comment: I tried out fbgrab, but it does not support "low-end bit depths". For my device the bit depth is 8. :( However, I looked at fbshot - http://www.sfires.net/fbshot/. fbgrab is based on fbshot and it supports 8 bit depth. fbshot works just fine.

Comment: fbgrab has been moved to [GitHub](https://github.com/GunnarMonell/fbgrab). I also had a problem with ancient version 1.2 which did not handle RGB565 well - fixed by update to the recent version.

Answer (score 7):

You can simply capture the framebuffer to a file and open it in any raw image viewer or try online eg: https://rawpixels.net/

```
cat /dev/fb0 > fbdump
```

Comment: This online converter didn't work for me, but here I found a Perl script that did the conversion nicely: https://www.cnx-software.com/2010/07/18/how-to-do-a-framebuffer-screenshot/

Comment: Is it normal to get several megabytes of all zero content from this way of dumping /dev/fb0 ?

Comment: @matanster: a raw file like that is just every pixel in order. Since a terminal screen is mostly black, and black is #000, you are going to have a lot of zeros to represent black pixels.

Answer (score 1):

It might not be possible / easy to do it directly with ImageMagick.

The Linux kernel 4.2 documentation https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/v4.2/Documentation/fb/api.txt#45 says:

> Pixels are stored in memory in hardware-dependent formats. Applications need
>   to be aware of the pixel storage format in order to write image data to the
>   frame buffer memory in the format expected by the hardware.
>
> Formats are described by frame buffer types and visuals. Some visuals require
>   additional information, which are stored in the variable screen information
>   bits_per_pixel, grayscale, red, green, blue and transp fields.
>
> Visuals describe how color information is encoded and assembled to create
>   macropixels. Types describe how macropixels are stored in memory. The following types and visuals are supported.

A list of visuals and types follows, but the description is not enough for me to understand the exact formats immediately.

But it seems likely that it might not be a format that ImageMagick will understand directly, or at least you'd have to find out the used format to decide the ImageMagick options.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use cat to get the raw frame buffer data

`cat /dev/fb0 > fbdump.data`

*Note that this is in the native format of whatever your frame buffer is set to.*

To convert it ffmpeg is useful. Remember to set the size with `-s` and the pixel format with `-pix_fmt`

`ffmpeg -vcodec rawvideo -f rawvideo -pix_fmt rgb32 -s 800x480 -i fbdump.data -f image2 -vcodec png screenshot.png`

You can also open `.data` files in gimp but the format options are more limited.

lastly you can also use fbgrab to get a screenshot and convert directly to png format. That is, if your embedded target has it.

`fbgrab -d /dev/fb0 screenshot.png`