# Fastest image capture for screenshot command line tool

Tags: linux, performance, imagemagick, screenshot, x11

I am trying to find the fastest possible way to take fullscreen consecutive screenshots in GNU/linux without any human intervention.
So far I get:

```
$ time for i in {1..10}; do import -window root test-$i.png; done
real    0m9.742s
user    0m11.324s
sys     0m0.584s

$ time for i in {1..10}; do scrot test-$i.png; done
real    0m1.686s
user    0m1.528s
sys     0m0.060s
```

However, I would like something even faster than scrot. The system times have been taken in a decent (hardware-wise) desktop PC (running Ubuntu Linux). The funny thing is that it hosts a kvm machine (CrunchBang Linux) that returns:

```
$ time for i in {1..10}; do import -window root test-$i.png; done
real    0m7.591s
user    0m6.096s
sys     0m0.196s

$ time for i in {1..10}; do scrot test-$i.png; done
real    0m2.921s
user    0m2.440s
sys     0m0.120s
```

Hence, `ImageMagick` is faster but `scrot` slower!?! Hard Disk I/O doesn't seem to influence speed since I get almost identical timings.

What do you recommend for dramatically (or less dramatically) improving speed?

Thank you!

Comment: have you try with [framebuffer directly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1645181/taking-a-screen-shot-of-an-embedded-linux-framebuffer)?

Comment: This may seem promising. So far I only grab a blank terminal (not the X)... I will update a question/answer as soon as I work this out. Many thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The times your experiencing are probably influenced by transcoding the screen-image into a friendly PNG, or JPEG, format. Just use X's `xwd` (X dump display utility) to, literally, dump the screen from RAM to disk. Only convert the raw XWD files to another format when your ready to view/process them.

```
# Capture
time for i in {1..10}; do xwd -root -silent -out test-$i.xwd; done

# When ready to view
 mogrify -format PNG -path ./pngs test-*.xwd
```

You can even speed up the `xwd` process by only dumping a specific window; which, can be calculation beforehand.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. `xwd` is indeed faster (~37%) compared to `scrot` and returns `real: 0m1.249s, user: 0m0.636s, sys: 0m0.252s`. I will have it in mind for the future. However, I need the `png` files quite immediately. Using `xwd` with `mogrify` together is considerably slower: (real: 0m3.151s, user: 0m2.276s, sys: 0m0.360s).

Comment: That sound right. If instant PNG is a requirement, you can roll your own solution with libpng & optimize for speed with LLVM. But that might just shave 5~10% of what you experiencing with scrot. There's alot of examples of low-level GPU encoders out there, but again, the development time my not be worth 0.2s improvement. OpenMP might be the way to go with Imagemagick, see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17659916/imagemagick-only-uses-one-core/17755692#17755692) to use all your CPU cores.

Answer (score 2):

In my case I found scrot with jpeg compression the fastest:

```
time scrot test.jpg 
scrot test.jpg  0.05s user 0.01s system 72% cpu 0.084 total
```

```
time xwd -root -silent -out test.xwd
xwd -root -silent -out test.xwd  0.18s user 0.05s system 88% cpu 0.252 total
```